# Como fazer requisição no servidor utilizando o método COMET?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, servidor

Tenho um sistema, em que ele exibe arquivos do banco de dados, em forma de lista.

Faço a consulta no banco de dados a cada 5 segundos utilizando o método **Polling**.

Como faço para utilizar o método **Comet**? Já que este método não fica pedindo informação do servidor toda hora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É mais simples do que eu pensava inicialmente .. Basicamente, você tem uma página que não faz nada, até que os dados que você deseja enviar está disponível (por exemplo, uma nova mensagem é recebida).

Aqui está um exemplo muito básico, que envia uma seqüência simples após 2-10 segundos. 1 em 3 chances de retornar um erro 404 (para mostrar manipulação no exemplo que vem Javascript erro)

`msgsrv.php`

```php
<?php
if(rand(1,3) == 1){
    /* Fake an error */
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    die();
}

/* Send a string after a random number of seconds (2-10) */
sleep(rand(2,10));
echo("Hi! Have a random number: " . rand(1,10));
?>
```

Nota: Com um site real, executando isso em um servidor web regular, como o Apache irá rapidamente amarrar todos os "segmentos de trabalho" e deixá-lo incapaz de responder a outras solicitações .. Existem maneiras de contornar isso, mas recomenda-se a escrever um "servidor de longo poll" em algo como Python [torcida] (http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/), que não depende de um thread por pedido. [cometd] (http://cometdproject.dojotoolkit.org/) é um um popular (que está disponível em várias línguas), e [Tornado] (http://www.tornadoweb.org/) é um novo quadro feito especificamente para tais tarefas (que foi construído para o código de longa votação do FriendFeed) ... mas como um simples exemplo, o Apache é mais do que suficiente! Este script pode ser facilmente escrito em qualquer língua (eu escolhi Apache / PHP como eles são muito comuns, e aconteceu de eu ser executá-los localmente)

Então, em Javascript, você solicitar o arquivo acima (`msg_srv.php`), e esperar por uma resposta. Quando você começa um, você agir de acordo com os dados. Então você solicitar o arquivo e esperar novamente, agir de acordo com os dados (e repete)

O que se segue é um exemplo de uma página .. Quando a página é carregada, ele envia o pedido inicial para o arquivo `msgsrv.php` .. Se for bem sucedido, nós adicionamos a mensagem para os`# messages` div, depois de um segundo chamamos a função waitForMsg novamente, o que desencadeia a espera.

A segunda `setTimeout 1 ()` é uma taxa limitador realmente básico, ele funciona muito bem sem isso, mas se `msgsrv.php` * sempre * retorna imediatamente (com um erro de sintaxe, por exemplo) - você inundar o navegador e ele pode rapidamente congelar. Isso seria melhor ser feito verificando se o arquivo contém uma resposta JSON válido, e / ou manter uma execução total de solicitações por minuto / segundo, e parando de forma adequada.

Se os erros de página, ele acrescenta o erro para o `# messages` div, espera 15 segundos e depois tenta de novo (idêntico à forma como vamos esperar um segundo depois de cada mensagem)

A coisa agradável sobre esta abordagem é que é muito resistente. Se a conexão de clientes internet morre, ele expirará, em seguida, tentar reconectar - isto é inerente quanto tempo de votação funciona, não-tratamento de erros complicada é necessária

De qualquer forma, o `long_poller.htm`, usando o framework jQuery:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>BargePoller</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      body{ background:#000;color:#fff;font-size:.9em; }
      .msg{ background:#aaa;padding:.2em; border-bottom:1px #000 solid}
      .old{ background-color:#246499;}
      .new{ background-color:#3B9957;}
    .error{ background-color:#992E36;}
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function addmsg(type, msg){
        /* Simple helper to add a div.
        type is the name of a CSS class (old/new/error).
        msg is the contents of the div */
        $("#messages").append(
            "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
        );
    }

    function waitForMsg(){
        /* This requests the url "msgsrv.php"
        When it complete (or errors)*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "msgsrv.php",

            async: true, /* If set to non-async, browser shows page as "Loading.."*/
            cache: false,
            timeout:50000, /* Timeout in ms */

            success: function(data){ /* called when request to barge.php completes */
                addmsg("new", data); /* Add response to a .msg div (with the "new" class)*/
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Request next message */
                    1000 /* ..after 1 seconds */
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg, /* Try again after.. */
                    15000); /* milliseconds (15seconds) */
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        waitForMsg(); /* Start the inital request */
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages">
        <div class="msg old">
            BargePoll message requester!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-to-implement-basic-long-polling

Comment: Ta, pelo que eu entendi você está usando o método long polling. Gostaria do método Comet

Comment: meu desculpa que burro eu rs

Comment: @Mathdesigner47 espero que esta documentação possa te ajudar http://imasters.com.br/artigo/12129/php/comet-server-push-com-xhr-multipart/

Comment: rsrs. sem problemas, li o artigo, testei no meu programa e funcionou certinho

Comment: perfeito amigo da um plus ai que eu agradeço