# O que é long polling?

Tags: ajax, terminologia, longpolling

Sempre quando pesquiso sobre "atualizações periódicas" e "notificações em tempo real" para aplicações Web, me deparo com o termo *long polling*.

Pelo pouco que entendi, parece se referir à atualizações periódicas feitas com AJAX, por  exemplo, com um `setInterval` do JavaScript,

Mas eu gostaria de saber mais aprofundadamente:

- O que é *long polling*?
- Usar *long polling*, para fins de manter uma aplicação atualizada, gasta muito recurso do servidor?
- O termo long polling se aplica, na programação, apenas no contexto Web, AJAX, JavaScript e afins?

Comment: _Comet_ não tem a ver com _long polling_? Se sim, relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32563/64969

Comment: Olha, eu não sei se irá ajudar muito, mas achei um site bem informativo sobre Long Polling, caso queria dar uma olhada, acho que encontrará oque procura:
imasters.com.br/artigo/23436/javascript/veja-como-o-long-polling-pode-te-ajudar-a-desenvolver-aplicacoes-em-tempo-real/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Comment: Apenas para associar a pergunta com outra que possui uma exemplificação https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/64080/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-long-polling-e-o-normal-ajax

Answer (score 27, accepted):

O Long Polling é uma técnica que simula uma indisponibilidade do servidor para manter uma conexão HTTP aberta. Essa técnica foi criada a partir da necessidade de comunicação em tempo real com um servidor *web*.

**Contexto**

Com a necessidade de se obter dados em tempo real do servidor, antigamente, os desenvolvedores criavam rotinas que enviavam uma requisição de tempos em tempos (como você mesmo descreveu) para "perguntar" se havia mudanças no modelo de dados da aplicação. Caso houvesse, a resposta da requisição conteria esses dados e então os mesmos poderiam ser atualizados na aplicação.

Esse tipo de rotina consumia uma quantidade grande de recursos quando a aplicação tendia a ser escalável (crescer de forma acelerada).
Vamos simular:

Imagine uma página que envia a cada 5 segundos uma requisição AJAX para um *endpoint* específico a fim de descobrir se houve mudanças de notificações, por exemplo.
Isso não se torna um problema com poucos usuários simultaneamente conectados. Mas digamos que a aplicação cresça de 10 usuários para 100 usuários conectados simultaneamente.

Vamos pensar maior. Imagine 1.000 usuários conectados.
Em 5 segundos, 1.000 requisições serão enviadas para o mesmo *endpoint*. Após mais 5 segundos, mais 1.000 e assim por diante.
Dependendo da arquitetura da aplicação, isso começa a sobrecarregar o servidor. Especificamente aquele *endpoint*.

**"A solução" - Long Polling**

Quando um cliente faz uma requisição o servidor simula uma indisponibilidade de dados e faz com que a requisição HTTP não tenha resposta enquanto não houver mudanças no modelo dos dados da aplicação.

Isso resolve o problema? Sim e não.
Sim, por que não é necessário ficar enviando requisições de tempos e tempos para checar essas mudanças.
Não, por que isso causou outro problema de desempenho. As requisições HTTP não foram especificadas para isso. Estender uma requisição HTTP pode "parecer" resolver o problema da quantidade de requisição enviadas ao mesmo *endpoint*, mas na verdade ela também consome muito recurso justamente por que está sendo usada inadequada.

**A verdadeira solução - WebSockets**

Escrevi um post sobre WebSockets e sua implementação em Java (mas tem implementações pra quase todas as linguagens atuais).
Sugiro que dê uma olhada por que lá eu explico com detalhes sobre a especificação e também dou exemplos práticos que da pra reproduzir ai na sua casa.

[Comunicação em tempo real com WebSockets](https://andrewribeiroblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/05/comunicacao-em-tempo-real-e-implementacao-de-websockets-em-java-com-exemplo/)

Enfim..
Foque seu estudo em implementações WebSockets e seja feliz com a verdadeira comunicação em tempo real.