# Consultar inserções no banco de dados em tempo real

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Existe uma tabela no Mysql que sofre muitas inserções.
A aplicação precisa mostrar essas alterações para o cliente.
Atualmente a aplicação existente consulta, a cada 10 segundos, a tabela e mostra na tela o conteúdo dela.
Existe alguma forma que o próprio banco informa quando houver alterações na tabela? Ou existe uma forma de melhorar esse tipo de cenário?
A problemática é o loop infinito que o jquery fica, mandando a cada 10 segundos um post para capturar as informações no banco.

Answer (score 1):

Também estou com esse problema, então durante algumas pesquisas encontrei uma funcionalidade chamada [Triggers](https://www.devmedia.com.br/mysql-basico-triggers/37462)(Gatilho) no `MySql`.

A minha ideia é criar uma outra tabela com um Trigger que registre a alteração(tabela_atualizacao), onde ela tem seu campo(atualizacao tipo int) alterado sempre que houver algum `UPDATE`, `DELETE` ou `INSERT`.
Assim trazer as informações somente quando esse campo int for diferente e não sempre que mandar o `$.post`.

Sei que tem técnicas bem melhores mas estou deixando apenas uma opção ;).

Comment: Cogitou Long Polling ?

Comment: Estou dando uma estudada, nunca havia visto.

Comment: E WebSocket, já leu a respeito?

Comment: Acabei de encontrar isso tambem, mas onde trabalho se usa asp classico :( to achando que não funciona.

Comment: Li uma resposta aqui no stack, onde é mencionado que o Long Polling é uma boa idéia, no entanto ainda pode gerar uma sobrecarga de recursos pq vai contra ao seu propósito de criação. Menciona-se então que o WebSocket é a verdadeira solução... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254506/o-que-%C3%A9-long-polling