# Notificação Push Laravel e React Native

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, react-native, push-notification

Eu tenho uma aplicação web desenvolvida em Laravel, onde eu cadastro clientes, cadastro os pedidos para cada cliente onde é gerado um código do pedido e para cada pedido eu cadastro as etapas. Essa aplicação também serve de API para meu aplicativo feito em React Native, onde o aplicativo consome os dados retornados da aplicação. O cliente entra no App, coloca o código do pedido, então o App faz uma requisição na minha aplicação/api e retorna as etapas daquele pedido para o usuário.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte. Como posso fazer para que quando seja cadastrada uma nova etapa ou pedido na aplicação web, seja enviado uma notificação para o usuário? É possível fazer isso utilizando apenas o Laravel e o React Native?

Entenderam minha dúvida?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe algumas soluções para isso. Veja:

- [Long Polling](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/254506/o-que-%C3%A9-long-polling)
- [Web Socket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_G3y-pc7O0&t=1265s)
- [Push Notification no Android](https://www.webdevbr.com.br/push-notification-no-android-enviando-notificacoes-do-seu-servidor)